# ActiveResource::ResourceInvalid: Failed. issue while updating tags to Order in Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have rails code to add some tags to the order, it's working fine but for some orders, API returning below error.

```
    order = ShopifyAPI::Order.find(params[:id])
    order.tags = "TES"
    if order.save
      render status: 200, json: ['Tags added successfully']
    else
      render status: 403, json: ['Error while updating order tags']
    end
```

ActiveResource::ResourceInvalid: Failed. this the error is rasing.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I'm answering to my question. I have created an order with dummy data to test my functionality so due to that validation issues are raising in Shopify to assign tags to order.

```
@errors = #<ActiveResource::Errors:0x00007f8188706c30
        @base=#<ShopifyAPI::Order:0x00007f818819e6f8 ...>,
        @details={:shipping_address=>[{:error=>"zip is not valid for tennessee and united states"}]},
        @messages={:shipping_address=>["zip is not valid for tennessee and united states"]}>
```

We can easily find the errors from **Order** object after you attempt to save.